# Is having more RAM or a better CPU beneficial for my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, memory, cpu, gaming

I have recently bought a new laptop, an ASUS N56VJ-S4149H. I bought it to use it in all possible ways I could want, so that would be gaming downloading and streaming movies browsing the web and programming software. So far it has been running great but one thing annoys me a little bit.

I frequently play Mount&Blade: Warband (it's a great game and you should check it out). Everything runs smoothly but only when I turn down the 'Texture Detail'. Otherwise it will lag a lot and I can't really play.

Now my question is:
Is this a problem of not enough RAM? At first I was really sure it was but after thinking about for a while I'm not anymore. My computer only has 4 Gigabytes of RAM and there is still a slot open. So will the game's performance at higher graphical settings improve if I add another 8 Gigabytes?

The computer has an Nvidia GeForce GT 635M inside and an Intel Core i5 3230M CPU with 2,6 GHz.

Comment: What video card do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything runs smoothly but only when I turn down the 'Texture Detail'

Likely your graphics hardware doesn't have enough video RAM.

I may be oversimplifying, but if you don't have enough video RAM, the game must move textures in and out of VRAM as needed. This is always going to be slower than the GPU using textures from its own RAM directly.

More RAM or a faster CPU would not help this.  You would need a GPU with more VRAM.

One other thing to look at is this: you may try to go into the BIOS and see if there is a setting called "AGP Aperture."  You may need to adjust this setting up or down.  I don't know too much about how to determine the optimal value.

Answer (score 1):

It is your graphics card.
As @ultrasawblade points out you may be able to do a bit better by increasing AGP aperture size, but don't expect miracles. There may also be a setting for shared memory in the BIOS and increasing that will give you more memory for graphics but it decrease the amount of memory available for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a graphics shortcoming. While more memory isnt expensive, I doubt it will alleviate this.